# JSonArray to String for parsing with GSon

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I have been give this method for parsing a JSonArray

```
private List<User> parseUserList(String jsonArray) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    // Declares the list type
    Type listType = new TypeToken<List<User>>() {}.getType();
    List<User> userList = gson.fromJson(jsonArray, listType);
    return userList;
}
```

I'm getting and an error on the line where i call this method. Is it wrong to call the toString() method there?

```
    JsonArrayRequest jsonArray = new JsonArrayRequest(
            Request.Method.GET,
            USERS_URL,
            null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONArray>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONArray response) {
                    List<User> list = parseUserList(response.toString());
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {...}
            }
    )
```

Also, is this a suboptimal way to turn a JSonArray into a list?

Comment: can you tell me what is the content of this::response.toString()

Comment: response is the JSonArray we retrieved. Im trying to turn it into a string so i can call the parseUserList method.

Answer (score 0):

If the Json array received in the response is correct,

then there would be no error at toString to get the corresponding json.

I would say please check the JSON object you are receiving in the json array is equivalent POJO for the User class.

hope, that helps!!

Comment: I think i fixed it. What was wrong (in case someone else comes around) is that the parameters for the JsonArrayRequest are just three:
 - A String with the URL or whatever will get you the info , the Response listener and the ErrorResponse listener. The other two parameters should not be there.